# ProcessingException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of X out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

```
private <T> T[] getObjects(Class<T> tClass, String version) {
    String subUrl = "/versions/" + version;
    return ClientBuilder.newClient()
                        .target(url)
                        .request()
                        .get(new GenericType<T[]>(tClass) {});
}
```

Here the json object

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"test",
      "country":"USA"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"test_1",
      "country":"cameroon"
   }
]
```

The call of getObjects method:

```
X[] x = getObjects(X.class, currentVersionName);
```

i get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of X out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3eb91815; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:875)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:248)
    ... 38 more
```

i use those dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe there's already enough for a resteasy/jackson expert, but I would ask: do you have the exception trace at the bottom? (from the last "Caused by" to the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change:

```
private <T> T[] getObjects(Class<T> tClass, String version)
```

to

```
private <T> T[] getObjects(Class<T[]> tClass, String version)
```

And your caller will be

```
X[] x = getObjects(X[].class, currentVersionName);
```